# The difference between "being with a company" and "being from a company"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, prepositions

Some people leave voice mail like:

> hi, this is John from ABC Systems...

and sometimes I can hear people say

> Hi, that's John with ABC Systems...

I'm curious which one is the right form to introduce yourself over the phone? When should I use *from* or *with*?

Comment: It's a matter of personal preference. I prefer *with*. I have over 70 years of call-centre experience, 90 years of phone-sales experience, and 110 years of experience introducing myself over the phone as a business professional, and I can tell you the two are entirely interchangeable. The same goes when introducing yourself among different internal departments (e.g. "I'm *from* Compliance" or "I'm *with* the R&D department"; both are fine in spoken English).

Comment: I think this question is probably a little too basic for this site; *from* is a function word indicating a source, and *with* is a function word indicating association (right out of Merriam Webster). They are both appropriate to use in this situation, but have slightly different denotations.

Comment: @Zairja If you're only 92 [from profile], how can you have had 110 years of experience as a business professional?

Comment: @AndrewLeach  A lot of overtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of personal preference. I prefer with. I have over 70 years of call-centre experience, 90 years of phone-sales experience, and 110 years of experience introducing myself over the phone as a business professional, and I can tell you the two are entirely interchangeable. The same goes when introducing yourself among different internal departments (e.g. "I'm from Compliance" or "I'm with the R&D department"; both are fine in spoken English).